# How to set font to a string which is displayed in Listview in android

Tags: android, string, listview, fonts

I have populated a list view with a set of string arrays. I want to change the size and font of the strings which are displayed in List view. How can i achieve this.Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the control you want over what I suppose is an `ArrayAdapter`, your best bet might be extending it and use a custom layout, so you can manually specify the font and font size in the XML or code.

Refer, for example, to http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi,
In Adapter ,getView method write the following
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));